# GCM push notification with android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Recently, I've tried to learn GCM and make a test application that will get the push notification for android through androids official site. However, I find the tutorial difficult for me. Are there any simple and easy tutorial for a novice like me to learn GCM push notification without the use of a server for android ?

Comment: this guide is with server although it is super readable and understandable, at least for me. try this one :)
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: @JozeRi that tutorial is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

there are lots of tutorial for GCM, here are some one :

1. https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html
2. https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html
3. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
4. http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/
5. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

I hope above point will help you.

Answer (score 1):

https://console.developers.google.com/
Click the above link to registered the application and On "Google Cloud Messaging for Android" API.
Copy the Browser Key and Sender/Project Key.

Follow a follwing link.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html